# How does this pop-function work?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I would like to understand the following pop-function.

```
struct list_node{
    int key;
    list_node* next;
    list_node(int k, list_node* n)
    : key(k), next(n);
    {}
};


class stapel{
    private: list_node* top_node;
    public: void pop (int value);
};

void stapel::pop()
{
    list_node* p=top_node;
    top_node=top_node -> next;
    delete p;
}
```

I know the pop-function removes the topmost node of a stack. So you have a pointer `p`, that points to the same node like the pointer `top_node`. I have difficulties understanding the next line.  `top_node->next` means the same like `(*top_node).next` and `top_node` is of type `list_node`, which is like a box that consist a key, a next-pointer and their values. Now I can't understand what `top_node->next` really means. I know next will become the next `top_node` pointer but why?

Comment: There should be code in pop() to check if top_node != 0 before using top_node->next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void stapel::pop()
{
    list_node* p = top_node;      // Get pointer to top of stack
    top_node = top_node->next;    // Find the next item in the stack, assign it to now be the top
    delete p;    // Delete the current top
}
```

You basically told the stack that the new "top" is the node that used to be 2nd from the top. You then delete the top node.

The way that the `next` line is working, is the same way that a "linked list" works. When you construct the stack (or linked list), for each node, you assign the value of that node (`key`), and a pointer to the next node (`next`).

```
top_node = top_node->next;
```

is simply getting the `next` member variable of the current node. That member variable happens to be a pointer to the next node, which was assigned when the current node was inserted into the stack.

**Edit**
As @Edward noted, it would also be a good idea to check that `top_node` is not `nullptr`. If it were, you would hit an exception when you tried to access the `next` member. So you could modify this function as:

```
void stapel::pop()
{
    if (top_node == nullptr)
        return;

    list_node* p = top_node;
    top_node = top_node->next;
    delete p;
}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that a check for `nullptr` in there would be prudent.